# How to "watch" sencha build process?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am working on a Ext JS project and I need to compile JSB3 file using Sencha build. I just wanted to know if there is a way to automate the build process. When I use "watch" Sencha Cmd shows it as unknown command. 
I am using Sencha Cmd v6 and Ext Js 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `sencha app watch` in the application root folder. Now when you change anything in your project the build will be run automatically.

The other commands which can be interesting for your are `sencha app build production` and `sencha app build testing`

You can also use `sencha help SomeCommand` and it will print you all the options about that command.

You can learn more at http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html#extjs-_-cmd_app_-_development_mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Actually, the command I am using for build purpose is : sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .  Can you please suggest me how to use "watch" with this command?

Answer (score 1):

**You looking for this i think**

- sencha app watch
- sencha app refresh
- sencha app build

these are cammands use to watch refresh and build a sencha application
for example::
if you are locally and using xampp
C:>cd xampp/htdocs/foldername/applicationname
and then sencha app watch

Comment: you have to run these cammands in the application root folder

Comment: Thanks Salman. But the build command I am using is **sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .**  Is there any way?

Comment: read the third option Deployment in the above guide link i posted

Comment: sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3 this one is used to generate a  JSB3 file

Comment: Yes I got the point, but there is no mentioning about "watch". On building, I am getting those two files as mentioned (all-classes.js + app-all.js)  but the problem is, each time I modify a file I have to type in this command in the terminal. That's why I thought if there would have been a watch command particularly with this format , it would be a lot more easier process.

Comment: ''watch'' is not a cammand ''sencha app watch'' this is a cammand

Comment: there are specific cammands speciafy by sencha cmd you cant use your own cammands

Comment: So, we cant "watch" build with **sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d** format ?? Thanks anyway.

Comment: once you build it and then you try to watch it here is the cammand which will watch your complete app including your new build file. ''sencha app watch''.